# Angular 6 with API in Codeigniter

Tags: angular, ngxs

I want to use **Angular 6** with **NGXS** for frontend and **Codeigniter 3** for backend. How can I combine the two, to call the api from CI in Angular NGXS

I have tried following steps:

- Created angular project using command: ng new {project name}
- Created a login API in CI
- Installed NGXS store and updated the app.module.ts file to include it
- In login.state.ts file I have added following code, which gives me following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404

```
import { State, Action, StateContext, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Login } from '../models/Login';
import { LoginUser } from '../actions/login.action';

export class LoginUserModel {
    login: Login[];
}

@State<LoginUserModel>({
    name: 'login',
    defaults: {
        login: []
    }
})
export class LoginState {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    @Action(LoginUser)
    authenticate({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<LoginUserModel>, { payload }: LoginUser) {
        this.http.post("http://localhost/CI/api/User/authenticate" , payload ).subscribe(response => {
            console.log("res=>"+response);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `angular-cli` you may probably go for a proxy to bypass CORS issues like this,

Create a `proxy.conf.json` file at the root of your project with the below contents

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

**Note:** This workaround is recommended only for development purposes, you should not have this in your production server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: David :Can you please explain me how can it be done on production server.Also on local server we need to call api like  " api/CI/api/User/authenticate " ? But are angular works on port 4200  so will it work ?

Comment: In Prod, you will not be making CORS calls , hence you won't have facing any issues. and the `/api/*` will intercept all calls which has the term `api` in it and you don't have to make any change in the URL while calling.